# How to determine the architecture of running process from the command line

Tags: terminal, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I would like to get the architecture of running processes from the command line (similarly to the "Kind" column in the Activity Monitor).

Comment: Apparently Apple does not expose this information in sysctl().  Someone reverse-engineered Activity Monitor ( https://rud.is/b/2021/03/13/retrieve-process-run-time-architecture-on-apple-silicon-macs-on-the-command-line-with-archinfo/ ) and made a CLI tool for it.

Comment: @vykor Thanks! Post it as an answer so that I can accept it!